# Reporting network errors to users

Tags: ios, networking, user-experience

NOTE: This is more of a "philosophical" question than a technical one.

So, I'm writing an iPad app which syncs its data to a backend which I also wrote. The sync works well, on a *good* network like the one at my apartment.

But in a slow or otherwise mediocre network like the public one in a Starbucks or my office it has a tendency to error out. In my testing, when it fails (albeit, infrequently) on these mediocre networks it's a timeout or "could not connect to the server" scenario, and the second attempt has consistently succeeded, resulting in a successful sync.

So my question is about how or whether to report these errors to the user. Right now I quietly report all errors to the user ( **using an unobtrusive error mark, not a modal dialog** ), but it's annoying in these scenarios because the next sync (has so far) always succeeded.

For some context: My app syncs in the background, continuously, as local changes are spotted and pushed to the server and as a long-polling background thread watches for changes on the server and pulls them downstream to the app.

My thought is that when I sync, I should try (for example) 3 times, breaking out on the first successful attempt. Only if all three attempts fail should I report an error to the user.

Is this a reasonable idea? **Or is this a terrible idea?**

Thanks,

Comment: Present it with an icon IMO. If you're going to continuously go out and try to sync it, then it's possible the user is seeing this pop-up multiple times a day. An icon to show the status is much less intrusive and even more informing - now the user can know when his data is synced.

Comment: Right now when there's a sync error I show a little badge with an exclamation point in it on the settings UITabBarItem. So there's no annoying modal block. The user, on tapping the settings tab can easily see the error message and email us the erroneous sync log. The thing is, that little red dot shows up for any error, and so it shows when there's any network issue, and usually goes away the next time the user makes an edit that the app wants to push upstream. So on bad networks that dot comes and goes, which is less annoying than a modal popup, but still kind of sucks.